# How to extract and display specific rows from CSV file in java?

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

I want data to be extracted based on   user input. Program asks for date input from user and based on that input all the records having that date should be fetched. How to do that?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour], read [ask], and go through the [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) to improve the quality of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSV files are just comma separated files. So you can read the csv file like any other file using the Reader class and then use the split function to seperate the columns.

First, you can read the file and store it in 2-D string array. And then filter the records according to the user input.